# Sum rule for sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have the following proof of the sun rule for sequences :
We have the two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ where $(a_n)\rightarrow a $ and $(b_n)\rightarrow b $. 
We also observe that $$0\leq |c(a_n-a)+d(b_n-b)|\leq |c||a_n-a|+|d||b_n-b| .$$
We know that both $(a_n-a) $ and $(b_n-b)$ are null sequences so using sum rule and sandwich theorem for null sequences (take as given here) we conclude that $(c(a_n-a)+d(b_n-b))\rightarrow 0 $ so $$(ca_n+db_n-(ac+bd))\rightarrow 0 \ \Rightarrow (ca_n+db_n) \rightarrow ac+bd , $$ since $(x_n-x)\rightarrow 0  \iff (x_n)\rightarrow x. \ \ \square $

Is this a valid proof or are there holes?

Comment: That looks fine to me

Comment: you did it really well ;-)

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to do this but would you mind taking a look at my proof for null sequences? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976174/sum-rule-for-null-sequences